# Liferay: Is it possible to define initialization dependency by portlets?

Tags: dependencies, initialization, liferay, portlet

I have two portlets: Portlet-A and Portlet-B.

Portlet-A make some data initialization and stores this in shared scope.

Portlet-B during initialization requires this data (from Portlet-A) from shared scope.

However, I need to define that Portlet-A has to be started (rendered) before the Portlet-B.

Is it possible by Liferay to define some order of initialization, or something like portlet dependency?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you require Portlet-A to be rendered before Portlet-B on the same page.

Then you can define this in the `liferay-portlet.xml`: `<render-weight>50</render-weight>` the more the `render-weight` the more quickly the portlet will render or in other words if the `render-weight` of Portlet-B is less than Portlet-A then it will render after Portlet-A.

More explanation regarding `render-weight` in the [DTD](http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-portlet-app_6_1_0.dtd)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

As per my knowledge, Liferay does lazy loading for portlets, so you cannot gurantee the order of the portlet initialization as well as portlet `doView()` calling.

The problem you are facing is the common issue whenever you are working with multiple portlets on a single page.

Here, the common workaround is that, the setter portlet (in your case portlet A) should set the property in the `processAction()` method and getter portlet( portlet B) should take that from `doView()`.

The reason is because, you cannot gurantee the order of the `doView()` but, if you are firing actionURL, the `processAction()` will always be called before doView().

So, the attribute will be available to all other portlet while rendering UI. Guranteed!